# trying to see what is causing the sigsev fault

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {


   long size = 10000000;

   long i = 0;

   while (i < size) {
    printf("%d\n", i);  
    i++;


}

   return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

/*
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++


but commenting out printf, i get no error - even traced in a debugger and jumping to   breaks after the while loop, i am able to get i reach the 10 billion mark.
just like below - 


++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
*/


#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {


long size = 10000000;

long i = 0;

while (i < size) {
    //printf("%d\n", i);    
    i++;


}

return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You are using wrong specifier for `long` which invokes **undefined behavior**. Use `%ld` instead.

Comment: good suggestion - but did just that - printf("%ld\n", i); - still i get segfault...

Comment: i know this is a very simple thing - i am just bothered as what limitations i am reaching...

Comment: you are right it works in your environment - could it have something to do with - glibc? - or linux environment maybe?

Answer (score 2):

You should use `%ld` to `printf` a `long` value (`%d` is for `int` instead).

For [`printf()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf):

> arguments specifying data to print. **If any argument is not the type expected by the corresponding conversion specifier, or if there are less arguments than required by format, the behavior is undefined**. If there are more arguments than required by format, the extraneous arguments are evaluated and ignored

Comment: thanks - herohuyongtao - tried that already printf("%ld \n", i) , sad to say i still get an error... (SIGSEGV)

Answer (score 0):

Your debugger should be able to provide a backtrace so you can see what function is on top of the stack  ( ie currently running ) at time of the segfault.  In gdb, this would be the `bt` commnd.

Comment: you are right Dan- i need to see the program stack and check what is causing the segfault in my environment...